# Error when executing multiple specs in firefox or edge or chrome in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, frontend, cypress

- To Be precise, execution is not happening when i run multiple spec files in firefox or edge or chrome browser. execution stops with following error

> Error: read ECONNRESET
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)  {   errno: 'ECONNRESET',   code: 'ECONNRESET',   syscall: 'read' } Error:
> read ECONNRESET
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)

- For Chrome, even though when using "chromWebSecurity": false in cypress.json, till 7 - 8 specs(number varies) it will run after it stops execution and shows following error

> Failed to connect to Chrome, retrying in 1 second (attempt 61/62)

> Failed to connect to Chrome, retrying in 1 second (attempt 62/62)
>
> Cypress failed to make a connection to the Chrome DevTools Protocol
> after retrying for 50 seconds.

```
This usually indicates there was a problem opening the Chrome browser.

The CDP port requested was 62236.

Error details:

Error: could not find CRI target
    at lazyAssLogic (C:\Users\manojkiran.yerrapotu\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.9.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\lazy
-ass\index.js:110:14)
    at Object.lazyAss (C:\Users\manojkiran.yerrapotu\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.9.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\la
zy-ass\index.js:115:28)
    at findStartPage (C:\Users\manojkiran.yerrapotu\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.9.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\browsers\pro
tocol.js:56:23)
```

Configurations used:

cypress: ^4.9.0 (latest)

OS: windows7

ram: 16gb

Comment: Open issues: 
1) https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7873
2) https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found following solutions

**To Solve Chrome/Edge issue**:
disable GPU (Graphics processing Unit)

add this code in plugins/index.js

```
on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
    if ((browser.name === 'chrome' || browser.name === 'edge') && browser.isHeadless) {
      launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu');
      return launchOptions
    }
  });
```

In cypress 4.11.0 **firefox** issue is also resolved

Answer (score -1):

overwrite your hosts file
add this
127.0.0.1 localhost