# Cypress error while running Sample Test. Cypress crashed and shows error ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, cypress

Please help if anyone knows how to resolve this error.

When I tried to run the cypress Sample Test it crashed and showing the error below :

Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
{
errno: 'ECONNRESET',
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read'
}
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)

I am using cypress the first time. so please If anyone knows please help.

When I run the same in Macbook then it's working fine but not for windows.

Nodejs: 12.14.0
windows: 10

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about this issue? Like what browser you're experiencing this on, what version of Cypress you're using? There is a post here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709875/error-when-executing-multiple-specs-in-firefox-or-edge-or-chrome-in-cypress which is almost the same error message and that user has fixed it by adding a "--disable-gpu" flag. Maybe that might work?

Comment: @nuclearcat Tried that Solution also added code in plugins/index.js. But nothing happened. No Solution. The browser is "Chrome" and "Cypress: 6.4.0". Can you please help me to solve this problem? As it's working fine on Mac now I don't understand why it's not working on Windows. Do I need to buy a mac for cypress?

Comment: can you please post an example of the code you're using so we can attempt to reproduce the error on our machine.
ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead usually means that there has been an error communicating with the browser. How are you running the Cypress tests? Headlesss, or using the UI? Does the UI open?

Comment: @nuclearcat Well, I am using the cypress Example test from the UI on Chrome Browser. As I am new so I didn't write any code in windows Machine. Just running Sample Test which was provided by cypress itself like Action, waiting for all those Sample tests. When I click on those test cypress UI just closed and Showed me error ECONNRESET. I tried that GPU disable code but nothing happened.

Comment: @nuclearcat Checked on git issues/14175 but no solution. Those people working on Cypress they were running it on a Mac machine.  In Mac, it is working fine. To be honest you're the one who's talking on this issue else no one replying. I tagged people Jennifer whose member of cypress.

Comment: Do you use proxy?